# How do I print only the file part of a full pathname?

Tags: c++, c, printf, substring

Here is a quick recreation of the problem I'm facing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    char path[100] = "home/user/cvs/test/VSCode/Test.dll";
    char *pos = strrchr(path, '/');
if (pos != NULL) 
{
   *pos = '\0'; 
}
    printf("%s", path);
}
```

I find the last "/" in the path name, and need to print everything after the last "/", so the output needs to be:

```
Test.dll
```

However, with my current code the output is:

```
home/user/cvs/test/VSCode
```

Basically my code prints everything BEFORE the last "/" but I need to print everything AFTER the last "/".

Comment: You can do `printf("%s", pos + 1);` (and omit `*pos = '\0'`).  Also, I would do `char path[] = "home/user/cvs/test/VSCode/Test.dll";` (omit the array size since the compiler will infer it).

Comment: `\0` represents end of a string, thats why you get upto last / as you are updating it to \0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling `strrchr`, `pos` will point to the last occurrence of `/`. If you advance it by one, it will point to the beginning of the filename:

```c
char *pos = strrchr(path, '/');
if (pos != NULL) 
{
   ++pos; 
   printf("%s", pos); /* Note - printing pos, not path! */
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is perfect!!

Comment: If `pos` _is_ `NULL` (meaning there are no `/` characters) you should probably set it to `path` and move the `printf` outside the test.